# Form PHP sem o campo email

Tags: php, email, envio-de-email

Gostaria de saber um método para enviar um `form` que não tem o campo `email`. Terá apenas três campos: `Nome`, `Telefone` e `Cidade`.

Porém, quando envio chega assim

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O código que tenho:

```
<?php

require_once('PHPMailer-master/PHPMailerAutoload.php');

PHP_OS == "Linux" ? $quebra_linha = "\n" : $quebra_linha = "\r\n";

$nome = trim($_POST["nome"]);
$tel = $_POST["telefone"];
$cid = $_POST["cidade"];

switch ($cid) {
    case "ipatinga":
        $destino = "mmarcelovictor@gmail.com";
        break;
    case "fabriciano":
        $destino = "mmarcelovictor@gmail.com";
        break;
    case "timoteo":
        $destino = "mmarcelovictor@gmail.com";
        break;
}


$email = "<br><b>NOME:</b> ".$nome."<br><b>TELEFONE:</b> ".$tel." <br>        <b>CIDADE:</b> ".$cid."</body></html>";

$mail = new PHPMailer();

$mail->IsMail();
$mail->SetFrom($eml, $nom);
$mail->Subject    = "Agendamento de visita";
$mail->MsgHTML($email);
$mail->AddAddress($destino, utf8_decode('Unimed'));


if (!$mail->send())
    $msgerro = "Não foi possível enviar sua mensagem de contato. Tente novamente dentro de alguns instantes.";
else
    $msgerro = "Sua mensagem de contato foi enviada com sucesso!";

?>
```

Como fazer com que invés de `Root User` e `root@localhos.dreamhost.com.br` tenham dados personalizados?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

É bom que você coloque um usuário e senha autenticado para ser usado para enviar o email.

**[Veja o seu código funcionando aqui](http://solutionsagencia.com.br/phpmailerteste/).**

Note que eu adicionei variáveis que fazem a autenticação `smtp` para que o envio seja feito da melhor forma. Esta autenticação usará um email verdadeiro para o envio do email.

Adicionei também a variável `$eml` e `$nom` que será o email e nome personalizado que você deseja.

Segue abaixo o código completo:

```
<?php

require_once('PHPMailer-master/PHPMailerAutoload.php');

PHP_OS == "Linux" ? $quebra_linha = "\n" : $quebra_linha = "\r\n";

$nome = trim($_POST["nome"]);
$tel = $_POST["telefone"];
$cid = $_POST["cidade"];

switch ($cid) {
    case "ipatinga":
        $destino = "mmarcelovictor@gmail.com";
        break;
    case "fabriciano":
        $destino = "mmarcelovictor@gmail.com";
        break;
    case "timoteo":
        $destino = "mmarcelovictor@gmail.com";
        break;
}


$email = "<br><b>NOME:</b> ".$nome."<br><b>TELEFONE:</b> ".$tel." <br>           <b>CIDADE:</b> ".$cid."</body></html>";

$mail = new PHPMailer();

$mail->IsMail();
$mail->isSMTP();
//$mail->SMTPDebug = 2; retire o comentário para debugar
//$mail->Debugoutput = 'html';
$mail->Host = "mail.seusite.com.br"; //servidor smtp
$mail->Port = 25; //a porta do servidor smtp
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;
$mail->Username = "seuemailpersonalizado@email.com.br"; //email que vai ser usado para enviar o email
$mail->Password = "senha"; //senha do email que vai ser usado para enviar o email

$eml = "seuemailpersonalizado@email.com.br"; //dados personalizados que você deseja (email)
$nom = "Seu Nome Personalizado"; //dados personalizados que você deseja (nome)

$mail->SetFrom($eml, $nom);
$mail->Subject    = "Agendamento de visita";
$mail->MsgHTML($email);
$mail->AddAddress($destino, utf8_decode('Unimed'));


if (!$mail->send())
    $msgerro = "Não foi possível enviar sua mensagem de contato. Tente novamente dentro de alguns instantes.";
else
    $msgerro = "Sua mensagem de contato foi enviada com sucesso!";

?>
```

Comment: Ótimo Wendell.

Esta autenticação é apenas para o email base ou para cada correspondente a determinada cidade? Serão três emails diferentes, um para cada cidade.

Comment: @MarceloVictor esta autenticação é para o email que será usado para enviar o email para os correspondentes, independente da quantidade de correspondentes você precisa apenas de uma autenticação.

Comment: Entendido. Muito obrigado pela ajuda  @Wendell

Answer (score 0):

A configuração do `PHPMailer` aparentemente está correta, no entanto as variáveis que define o nome e o email do remetente *$mail->SetFrom* não estão definidas: **$eml** e **$nom** , pelo menos no código que postou aqui, faça um teste substituindo os parametros por valores fixos, por exemplo

```
$mail->SetFrom('email@teste.com', 'Nome do Remetente');
```

Comment: Olá rubStackOverflow. Fiz isso, porém o email nem chega.